# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas, set mapping key value error

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, contract

The contract function is

```
function _removeFlag(address sender) internal {
    //remove if in record
    if (mapping1[sender] > 0) {
       mapping1[sender] = 0;
    }
}
```

when my test case running into this function , show an error like:

truffle>: truffle test

`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas`

If I set it with `mapping1[sender] = 1;` the error disappears.

Version information:

Truffle v5.4.0 (core: 5.4.0)
  Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
  Node v16.4.2
  Web3.js v1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your account balance : `balance = web3.eth.getBalance(someAddress);` then try to specify the gaslimit `contractInstance.createProposal("ADHD", "Foo", 2, {from: web3.eth.accounts[1], gas:3000000})`